# IllegalArgumentException... no ':' in url exception

Tags: java, java-me

**no ':' in url exception**  am getting that exception when am trying to execute this fragment of code...

```
FileConnection conn;

try{
    conn =(FileConnection)Connector.open("/NewFile.xml");
    if(!conn.exists())
       conn.create();
    _screen.add(new RichTextField("Connection Established..."));
    _screen.add(new SeparatorField());

} catch(IOException ioe) {
       _screen.add(new RichTextField(ioe.getMessage()));
}
```

where /NewFile.xml is a xml file in my Project

Comment: What are FileConnection and Connector?

Comment: I thin it will be this http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/

Comment: I have a question - where is Your file? Is it included in the JAR or are You trying to load it from file system?

Answer (score 5):

You have to write the path like

file:///NewFile.xml/

```
try{ 
conn =(FileConnection)Connector.open("file:///NewFile.xml/"); 
if(!conn.exists()) 
  conn.create(); 
_screen.add(new RichTextField("Connection Established...")); 
_screen.add(new SeparatorField());

}
catch(IOException ioe)
{
     _screen.add(new RichTextField(ioe.getMessage()));
}
```

[Getting Started with fileconnection](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/)

Comment: or, perhaps more convenienty, create a java.io.File object, then call toUrl() on that. It saves you having to muck about with obscure file URL syntax.

Comment: Yes, it needs an absolute url, not a relative one.

Answer (score 1):

Use File, and then toUrl()

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a file connection, but can read the data from jar directly by using input stream:

```
Class.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/NewFile.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

A file access URL starts with "file://"...

Answer (score -1):

add prefix "http://" into your file path or url